# How to apply \regex_replace_all until the text stops changing?

Tags: expl3

Look at this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\l__foo{a a a b a a a}
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a (.+) a }{ [ \1 ] } \l__foo
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a (.+) a }{ [ \1 ] } \l__foo
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a (.+) a }{ [ \1 ] } \l__foo
\l__foo
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

It renders:

```
[[[b]]]
```

As you see, I have to use `\regex_replace_all` three times. It's an obvious code duplication. Moreover, it would not be acceptable when the input (`a a a b a a a`) would not be a constant but a parameter of a command. How can I get rid of code duplication and make sure `\regex_replace_all` is applied to the text until it stops changing?

Please, don't suggest to change the regular expression, it's just a motivating example, my real use case is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `T` form that runs the true branch if a match was made:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\l__foo{a a a b a a a}
\cs_new:Npn\foo_aux: {
\regex_replace_all:nnNT { a (.+) a }{ [ \1 ] } \l__foo \foo_aux:
}

\foo_aux:

\l__foo
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I understand, `\foo_aux` is being called recursively. However, I don't understand why do you need a colon after it? I remove it everywhere and the code works.

Comment: the colon is part of the name just like `aux` or the colon in `\tl_set:Nn` that is standard expl3 syntax convention for a function with no arguments it has nothing after the colon. If you have no colon then it is a variable like your `\l__foo` and expected to be used as an argument not executed directly. But this is just expl3 name conventions to tex you can call it `\khghf` with no `_` and no `:` and it will work. @yegor256  so you should leave the colon there:-)